# How to sort multidimensional array

Tags: perl, sorting

How would I go about sorting the following arrays in the following by the value in TIME?

```
$VAR1 = [
          {
            'TIME' => '45',
            'PLAYER' => '',
            'TYPE' => '6'
          },
          {
            'INFO' => 'Dissent',
            'TEAMFLAG' => '1',
            'PLID' => '8570',
            'TIME' => '85',
            'PLAYER' => 'Player1',
            'TYPE' => '4'
          },
          {
            'TEAMFLAG' => '1',
            'PLID' => '8570',
            'TIME' => '35',
            'PLAYER' => 'Player1',
            'TYPE' => '1'
          },
          {
            'TEAMFLAG' => '0',
            'PLID' => '145399',
            'TIME' => '60',
            'PLAYER' => 'Player3',
            'TYPE' => '1'
          },
          {
            'TEAMFLAG' => '0',
            'PLID' => '145248',
            'TIME' => '12',
            'PLAYER' => 'Player1',
            'TYPE' => '1'
          },
          {
            'TIME' => '0',
            'PLAYER' => '',
            'TYPE' => '10'
          }
]
```

The above is a datadump of `$data->{EVENTS}->{EVENT}` which I need sorting, so have tried the following but it doesn't sort:

```
my @sorted =  sort { $b->{TIME} <=> $a->{TIME} } $data->{EVENTS}->{EVENT};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hash and array elements are scalars. In this case, `$data->{EVENTS}->{EVENT}` is more speceifically a reference to an array. You want `@{ $data->{EVENTS}->{EVENT} }`.